# Getting ERROR in MatFormFieldModule is not an NgModule on npm start

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

When I give `npm start` for the first time,
getting `ERROR in MatFormFieldModule is not an NgModule. webpack: Failed to compile.`

When I edit a file and save, it automatically compiles successfully. Not getting what the error is.

Using `@angular/material@^2.0.0-beta.12`

Comment: have you added `MatFormFieldModule` in `@NgModule`?

Comment: Yes. I have added MatFormFieldModule in @NgModule

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this issue. I should not have added MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule from @NgModule. It worked as expected when I removed it. Thanks to @Bohdan Khodakivskyi for the clue